# grails compilation error - "package does not exist"

Tags: tomcat, grails, javac

I am new to grails and was following the trail by setting up a simple application with a helloWorld-Controller. After doing `create-app` and opening the interactive console, I am running into the following problem.

```
grails> create-controller projects | Compiling 10 source files. | Error Compilation error: startup failed: Compile error during compilation with javac. C:\dev\grails-2.3.5\timespent\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.50\src\java\org\grails\plugins\tomcat\TomcatKillSwitch.java:3: error: package org.apache.catalina does not exist

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
                              ^ 
C:\dev\grails-2.3.5\timespent\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.50\src\java\org\grails\plugins\tomcat\TomcatKillSwitch.java:4: error: package org.apache.catalina.startup does not exist 
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
                                      ^ 
C:\dev\grails-2.3.5\timespent\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.50\src\java\org\grails\plugins\tomcat\TomcatKillSwitch.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        private Tomcat tomcat;
                ^   
symbol:   class Tomcat   
location: class TomcatKillSwitch 
C:\dev\grails-2.3.5\timespent\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.50\src\java\org\grails\plugins\tomcat\TomcatKillSwitch.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        public TomcatKillSwitch(Tomcat tomcat, int serverPort) {
                                ^   
symbol:   class Tomcat
location: class TomcatKillSwitch 
C:\dev\grails-2.3.5\timespent\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.50\src\java\org\grails\plugins\tomcat\TomcatKillSwitch.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
                             ^   
symbol:   class LifecycleException   
location: class TomcatKillSwitch 
5 errors


1 error | Error Error running script create-controller projects: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) grails>
```

I tried `grails clean` and `grails refresh-dependencies compile` but the error is still popping up.

The full stacktrace goes on a little more but there seems to be nothing significant in there.

There is more than one tomcat on my system, but as far as I can see grails uses a bundled tomcat.

Can anyone tell why `javac` fails? After all, it is a fresh install and it didn't do much yet except for loading dependencies.

Comment: please cross check 1. set the grails and Java path and class path. also can you see the .grails getting created when you run refresh-dependencies in you home dir?

Comment: Hi, yes the `.grails` folder is present in my user's directory. I double-checked the environment variables. After adding the tomcat as external jar in the eclipse project build path and deleting the "`target`" folder in the project, the `create-controller` command and `run-app`are now (finally) running fine. Thanks.

Comment: What would this solution be if using IntelliJ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, see my comment above

> add the tomcat as external jar in the eclipse project build path
>   and delete the "target" folder in the project